# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument when using requests librarary

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram, python-requests-html

I am currently trying to use the requests library to print the followers of an Instagram account. However, requests is coming up with this error every time I run it

```
import requests
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 780, in get_code
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 833, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

my code is this

```
import requests

url = "https://instagram85.p.rapidapi.com/account/25945306/followers/"

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "instagram85.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Do you have any files locally that might shadow Python libraries? EINVAL is still odd though; there are only 2 errors mentioned in `read(2)`.

Comment: I suppose it could also be `open(2)` or something else. Could you try running under `strace` so we can see what syscall failed and with what arguments?